# Angular 8 Async call not waiting for promise to complete and results as bad request

Tags: typescript, async-await, angular8, angular-promise

i want my async call not to go to next statements until its completed, but its still going and also after completion of the request it results error as bad request even though the url path and http headers are correct.if i do it using observable and subscribe way its working but going to next statements before completing the request, so i thought promise async/await could help but am i doing anything wrong, any help is very much appreciable. Here is my code.

**myapp.service.ts**

```
//Because we are not using a type checker, so the response should be extracted. Add this function after the constructor for extract it.
private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res;
    return body || {};
  }
private handleError(error) {
    return throwError(error);
  }
async getEntityDependencies(entitytype: string) {
    try {      
      var authheader = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'accesstoken': this.accesstoken, 'Content-Type': 'application/json', })};

      return await this.http.get(this.endpoint, authheader).pipe(map(this.extractData), catchError(this.handleError)).toPromise();       
    } 
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

**newform.component.ts**

```
async CreateForm() {
  // const data = await this.rest.getEntityDependencies(this.dataservice.entitytype)
  await this.rest.getEntityDependencies(this.dataservice.entitytype).then((data: {}) => { // data is getting undefined since request results Bad request
    // my stuff using data...
  }, error => {
    console.log(error, "Error from API");
  });
}
```

Comment: I would suggest going through the official website for writing Services in angular

https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two issues in the code

first you don't need to `return await`

```
async getEntityDependencies(entitytype: string) {
    try {      
      var authheader = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'accesstoken': this.accesstoken, 'Content-Type': 'application/json', })};

      return this.http.get(this.endpoint, authheader)
         .pipe(
            map(this.extractData), 
            tap(data => console.log('data in service', data))
            catchError(this.handleError)
         ).toPromise();       
    } 
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

second this method

```
async CreateForm() {
  try
  {
     const data = await this.rest.getEntityDependencies(this.dataservice.entitytype);
     console.log('data', data);
  }
  catch(ex) {
     console.error(ex);
  }
}
```